# Как отправить файл в ASP.NET Core Web-API вместе с моделью?

Tags: .net-core, webapi

Буквально все руководства (что MS, что Metanit) описывают, как отправить один файл. Но этот файл нужно отправить вместе с дургими данными, и вот тут я поплыл.

Контроллер

```
[HttpPost("addwithfile")]
public ProductClass PostWithFile(IFormFile file)
```

Отрабатывает на ура: в swagger я вижу возможность добавить файл, он добавляется и передается.
Меняем контроллер:

```
public ProductClass PostWithFile(ProductClass pclass, IFormFile file)
```

из swagger пропадает возможность добавить файл, только поля модели
Если вручную пошаманить с postman'ом то получаю ошибку 415, Unsupported Media Type

Как можно за один POST передать в API данные формы и файл?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `[FromForm]ProductClass pclass`

Comment: Помогло, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web API по умолчанию назначает всем составным моделям источник [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Это означает, что тело запроса берётся целиком и десериализуется в модель. Но если тело запроса целиком занято моделью - где вы собираетесь передавать файл? Для него просто не остаётся места.

Поэтому, если вы собираетесь передавать модель и файл совместно - вы явно указать Web API, что ваша модель должна передаваться как часть формы (multipart/form-data).

Это достигается через указание атрибута [[FromForm]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```cs
public ProductClass PostWithFile([FromForm]ProductClass pclass, IFormFile file)
```

Подробнее обо всём этом можно прочитать тут: [Create web APIs with ASP.NET Core - Binding source parameter inference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#binding-source-parameter-inference-1)